How to perform a json schema validation request outside(and before) the backend?
I'm trying to separate the json schema validation step from my nodejs server (REST API). I'm using ajv package.
I don't know why but I always thought that Nginx was able to natively perform this kind of validation and since yesterday it seems that I was totally wrong ... With an external javascript module it's possible I think but it will be very slow.
Is there another solution with Nginx to perform these validation ? If not, what kind of server/arch will do the job ?
Ty !
